# Accessing single value in field using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, cursor

I'm pretty new to Python scripting (especially in ArcGIS). I would like to access a single element from a field and modify it. I understand that I can do this with cursors by searching the field column for the value (arcpy.da.SearchCursor) and then replacing it (arcpy.da.UpdateCursor), but this feels inefficient.

Is there a way to directly access an element without looping continuously?

Comment: You don't need a `SearchCursor` with an `UpdateCursor`. Use a `where_clause` when you call the `UpdateCursor` to limit it to only the records you're interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [commented by @user2856](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/393964/accessing-single-value-in-field-using-arcpy-with-arcgis-pro#comment644743_393964) using a where_clause on your UpdateCursor is all that is needed.

If you have variables `fc`, `fld` and `val` set to a feature class, a field name in that feature class, and a value in a text field respectively then this should work to change the value to a new value of "X":

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,fld,"{0} = '{1}'".format(fld,val)) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = 'X'
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```